# How to randomly unique change words color in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a script that changes the list items colors on anchor, when it is clicked randomly. My problem is that sometimes two words or more have the same color and I don't want that to happen. Anyone has any idea on how to do that?

#### My code:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var colors = ['#0071bc', '#ff00ff', '#fcee21', '#39B54A', '#00A99D', '#662D91'];
  $('li').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
<a>Change color</a>
```

#### A working Fiddle:

[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug03rx4a/1/)

Comment: Shuffle the array then pick the colors. If the number of items is less than the number of colors then you'll always have a unique color

Comment: @elclanrs, sorry, but the number if items in my case isn't necessarly less than the number of colors.

Comment: @Anonymous **1.** Shuffle the array. **2.** `pop()` the contents.

Comment: @PranavCBalan, and how would that work with my array?

Comment: @Anonymous `sorry, but the number if items in my case isn't necessarly less than the number of colors` Then how is supposed to have unique colors for each element when you're not having enough unique colors?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll keep in mind that, and I will use more colors. Thanks again.

Comment: @Anonymous Even in any case, if the number outruns, you can always, create a copy of the array if the `array.pop()` is `null` and then reinit the shuffled array! `:)`

Comment: @Anonymous : While Praveen's solution does do the trick, it's a pretty sub-optimal approach. The same result can be achieved with both much less code ánd much better performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896026/how-to-randomly-unique-change-words-color-in-javascript/35896751#35896751

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shuffle the array and use `array`'s `.pop()` method to get your uniqueness. `:)`

```js
$(function () {
  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var colors = ['#0071bc', '#ff00ff', '#fcee21', '#39B54A', '#00A99D', '#662D91'];
    colors = shuffle(colors);
    $('li').each(function() {
      $(this).css('color', colors.pop());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
<a>Change color</a>
```

<sup>*ps: Shuffle function stolen from [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charm. Good idea with shuffling the array.

Comment: @Marie I know. That's not possible, and you know that! `:)` How can you put uniquely three colours for five elements?

Comment: @Anonymous That's great to hear, half the credit should go to `elclanrs` and half to the answer from where I knicked the randomizing code. `:)`

Comment: @Anonymous Also make sure you have enough unique colours after shuffling, coz if there's another case, the see my comment to Marie. `:(`

Comment: but can prevent sibling repeats by not using `pop()` and use index modulo

Comment: Came across that topic, but I didn't knew I had to use pop(). Thanks again. I will accept your answer. I'll make sure I use more or exactly the same number of colors as the items.

Comment: @charlietfl Sure... yes, I would love to tell that, but this explanation is for getting the unique colours. `:)`

Comment: @Anonymous Also think about the fact - number of colours and number of items. `:)`

Comment: @Anonymous Even in any case, if the number outruns, you can always, create a copy of the array if the `array.pop()` is `null` and then reinit the shuffled array! `:)`

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing but with images(or images paths)? If yes can you help me with an start ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### The optimal solution

The only change you need to make to your existing code, is replacing ...

```
$(this).css('color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
```

... with ...

```
$(this).css('color', colors.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), 1));
```

---

#### How it works

The most efficient way to get unique colors, is to use [**the `splice()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in combination with `Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)` :

- The `splice()` method allows you to both (1) remove a single element from the `colors` array at a position you choose, and (2) return that element.
- `Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)` allows you to make that position a random position.

Because it only takes a single `for`-loop and a single splice operation per iteration, this approach is much more efficient than [**Praveen**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar)'s approach (where you first do a shuffle and then "pop" an element from the shuffled array).

An additional advantage, is that it requires very little code.

---

#### A demo

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var colors = ['#0071bc', '#ff00ff', '#fcee21', '#39B54A', '#00A99D', '#662D91'];
    var index, value;
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).css('color', colors.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), 1));
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>

<a href="#">Change color</a>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e9kcfqws/5/))

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing but with images(images paths I mean)? If yes, can you help me with an idea how would look?

Comment: @Ionut : Just put URLs in your array instead of color strings, and use `$(this).attr('src' url)` instead of `$(this).css('color', color)` to set the value. That should do it...

Comment: Wouldn't that randomize the image paths instead of images colors? I need to change the image paths, keep the images in same position but changing them with the same words images of different color. I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @Ionut : You lost me there... Please send me a Fiddle with a demo (to illustrate what you're trying to achieve) as a response to this comment. I'll be leaving for a meeting in 5 to 10 minutes, but I should be able to take a look at your Fiddle when I return from my meeting.

Comment: Thanks. I made the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/whje9h7s/2/. Now it's randomly changing the images. I don't want that. I need it to change the image color and keep images in the same position. And I thought about changing the images paths using a JSON maybe, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Ionut : Is it possible to use inline SVG images? Then, you could go for something like this --> https://jsfiddle.net/58ptjxmo/5/

Comment: I have img tags. I need them to be that way for another reason. So using SVG isn't going to help me. Isn't there another way?! I have the images in a slideshow and it needs to be responsive. If I will use text is not going to be fluid.

Comment: @Ionut : If you don't care about supporting Internet Explorer, consider using the `filter` property --> https://jsfiddle.net/whje9h7s/5/

Comment: Is it possible to use my own specific colors? Because I don't care about IE support. I tried hex colors in array but they don't work

Comment: @Ionut : Yes, you can. However, it's a bit tricky. The easiest way to do it, is to (1) make all your images the same color by default, (2) upload one of your images to http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-webkit-filter-effects-generator.html and (3) generate the correct values for `hue-rotate` by fiddling around in the editor.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for taking your time and helped me.

Comment: Okay. I will do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["Stackover", "flow", "Rocks", "Nice"];
    setInterval(function() {
        count++;
        $("#word").fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```